# Cannot convert value of type 'KotlinBoolean' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform

Im making a Multiplatform KMM project, and im having trouble assigning dynamic value to the button property.

Basically I have this like button which changes its states depending on `selected` property:

```
struct SelectFavouriteButton: View {
    
    @State var selected = false    
    let action: (Bool) -> Void
      
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            selected.toggle()
            self.action(selected)
        }) {
            Image(systemName: selected ? "heart.fill" : "heart" )
                .foregroundColor(.accentRed)
        }
    }
}
```

The view model from Kotlin part:

```
@Serializable
data class Data(
...
    var isLiked: Boolean? = null,
    var isSaved: Boolean? = null,
...
}
```

And the view where this button is called:

```
struct CellView: View {
    
    @State var advert: Data?

    var body: some View {

     // Cannot convert value of type 'KotlinBoolean' to expected argument type 'Bool'
     // Insert ' as! Bool'
     SelectFavouriteButton(selected: advert?.isLiked ?? false){ isPressed in   // Error is here
         self.action(isPressed, advert?.id ?? "" , false)   
     }

   }
}
```

Should I use mapping? If yes how do I do it in the current context?
Pls help

Comment: You need to convert advert?.isLiked to swift Bool first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin primitives transferred to `NSNumber` in swift, so try the following (not tested - idea only)

```
 let linked = advert.isLiked as? NSNumber // or NSNumber?
 SelectFavouriteButton(selected: linked?.boolValue ?? false){ isPressed in
     self.action(isPressed, advert?.id ?? "" , false)   
 }
```

Comment: Error is gone, lets see if returns the correct bool value
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

@Asperi's suggestion should work, but the reasoning is not quite right.

Kotlin primitives are perfectly transferable to ObjC primitives, and those are easily accessible from Swift.

But ObjC primitives such as `NSInteger` or `BOOL` do not support optionals. So when you declare an optional primitive in Kotlin, it is converted to `KotlinNumber`, as an object is needed to store an optional value in ObjC.

`KotlinNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber`, so you can use it that way:

```
isLiked?.boolValue
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the top search result for "convert bool to KotlinBoolean", I'll put this here for devs like me going the other way:

`let selected = KotlinBoolean(bool: swiftObject.selected)`